# Storing Iterator<Pojo> object of Reducer method to array

Tags: arrays, hadoop, mapreduce, iterator

I want to store 
    *Iterator values* 
which is the argument of Reduce method i.e

```
public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterator<Pojo> values,
        OutputCollector<IntWritable, SubArrayWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
```

in an custom ArrayWritable class object i.e PojoArrayWritable object .
I have already created PojoArrayWritable class and the code for that is

```
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.ArrayWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;

public class SubArrayWritable extends ArrayWritable
{
public SubArrayWritable() {
    super(Sub.class);
}
public SubArrayWritable(Sub[] values) {
    super(Sub.class, values);
}
}
```

And Sub.class has the following code-

```
import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.DoubleWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;

public class Sub implements Writable {
private IntWritable id = new IntWritable();
private LongWritable pno = new LongWritable();
private DoubleWritable sal = new DoubleWritable();

public IntWritable getid() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(IntWritable id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public LongWritable getPno() {
    return pno;
}

public void setPno(LongWritable pno) {
    this.pno = pno;
}

public DoubleWritable getSal() {
    return sal;
}

public void setSal(DoubleWritable sal) {
    this.sal = sal;
}

@Override
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    id.readFields(in);
    pno.readFields(in);
    sal.readFields(in);

}

@Override
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    id.write(out);
    pno.write(out);
    sal.write(out);
}


}
```

And in Reducer class

```
public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterator<Pojo> values,
        OutputCollector<IntWritable, SubArrayWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
```

I want to store the values object of Iterator to array i.e to object of SubArrayWritable , so how can i do that since i dont know the size/length of values object of Iterator so what will be the length of SubArrayWritable object that i will be creating ??

So at last basically I have `Iterator<Pojo> values`and i have to convert it to `array of Pojo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution for this -

```
    Pojo pojo=new Pojo();
    List<Pojo> list=new ArrayList<Pojo>();

    if (values.hasNext()) {
        pojo = values.next();
        list.add(pojo);
       }
```

now i can user this pojo object values which contains values of iterator object